# How to bind event to element and all children but only ever trigger it once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<a href="#" id="back-button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">
  <div class="nav-item-desc">Back</div>
</a>
```

And here is how I bind a click event:

```
$("#back-button").contents().addBack().off().on("click", function(e)
{
});
```

Now, when I click on the div (right on the text), the event gets fired once and when I click on the link (beside the text on the button), it gets fired twice.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just bind click event on `#back-button`??? As click event bubbles, this isn't an issue. BTW, you could still filter specific clicked element using `event.target`

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM, so `.contents().addBack()` is redundant.

Comment: Weird, I explicitely added .contents().addBack() because the event didn't trigger when I clicked beside the text. Now it suddenly triggers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$("#back-button").on("click", function(e){
    // e.target is the specific clicked element
});
```

Answer (score -2):

have a look at http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$("#back-button").contents().addBack().off().one("click", function(e){});
```